# How to Avoid CXF Generating Separate class rather than use exiting XMLRootElement Class(JAXB Class)

Tags: jaxb, jax-ws, cxf

I'm newbie to CXF and JAXB. I'm trying to generate WSDL from Java class(Bottom up Approach) using eclipse on CXF.

Created the Interface as fellows.

```
@WebService(name = "EBMData", targetNamespace = "http://business.kp.org/")
public interface EBMData {

    @WebMethod
    public @WebResult OPStatusDetails addEBMFields(InputFields fields);

    @WebMethod
    public @WebResult OPStatusDetails addOLIs(InputOLIs olis);


}
```

Request XML JAXB Class is as follows

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="InputFields")
@XmlRootElement(name="InputFields")
public class InputFields {

    @XmlElement(name="FieldName", required=true)
    String fieldName;

    @XmlElement(name="Oli", required=true)
    List<String> olis;

    public String getFieldName() {
        return fieldName;
    }

    public void setFieldName(String fieldName) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }

    public List<String> getOlis() {
        return olis;
    }

    public void setOlis(List<String> olis) {
        this.olis = olis;
    }



}
```

Response XML JAXB class is as follows

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="OPStatusDetails")
@XmlRootElement
public class OPStatusDetails {

    @XmlElement(name="returnMessage", required=true)
    String returnMessage;

    public String getReturnCode() {
        return returnMessage;
    }

    public void setReturnCode(String returnMessage) {
        this.returnMessage = returnMessage;
    }



}
```

Once the above class is created, Used new-> web Service and used the bottom up approach option. and generated the WSDL.

Once the WSDL is generated, Could notice a new package is created. with files AddEBMFields.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "addEBMFields", namespace = "http://business.kp.org/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "addEBMFields", namespace = "http://business.kp.org/")

public class AddEBMFields {

    @XmlElement(name = "arg0")
    private org.kp.business.xmls.InputFields arg0;

    public org.kp.business.xmls.InputFields getArg0() {
        return this.arg0;
    }

    public void setArg0(org.kp.business.xmls.InputFields newArg0)  {
        this.arg0 = newArg0;
    }

}
```

and AddEBMFieldsResponse.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "addEBMFieldsResponse", namespace = "http://business.kp.org/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "addEBMFieldsResponse", namespace = "http://business.kp.org/")

public class AddEBMFieldsResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "return")
    private org.kp.business.xmls.OPStatusDetails _return;

    public org.kp.business.xmls.OPStatusDetails getReturn() {
        return this._return;
    }

    public void setReturn(org.kp.business.xmls.OPStatusDetails new_return)  {
        this._return = new_return;
    }

}
```

Due to these files my Request XML is generating as follows, instead of arg0 field, it needs to be referenced from InputFields.java. Could you please help on this.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bus="http://business.kp.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bus:addEBMFields>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>
            <FieldName>?</FieldName>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <Oli>?</Oli>
            <Oli>?</Oli>
            <Oli>?</Oli>
         </arg0>
      </bus:addEBMFields>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And also I would like t

```
o know how my JAXB class should for the following soap request xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bus="http://business.kp.org/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <bus:addEBMFields>
             <!--Optional:-->
            <FieldName>?</FieldName>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <Oli>?</Oli>
            <Oli>?</Oli>
            <Oli>?</Oli>
          </bus:addEBMFields>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
```

to the EBMData interface.   By default, it will create wrappers for the operations.  Specifying BARE mode will use the types directly.